# How to move with green marker from Directions Service in real time

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, directions

I am making project with Geolocation API from Google. When you select Budova(Building in english) and then choose number of budova you will get a way to this building. I want to make realtime navigation and update every 3000ms that green A point. Is there any solution for this? Here is my URL: http://vyvoj.nwt.cz/navigace2_zaloha/

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?